# Generating Isabelle HTML documentation *without proofs*

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I wish to generate HTML documentation for Isabelle theories (e.g. the HOL session) but **without including the proofs**.

That is, I would like to produce pages like http://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/Nat.html
but instead of, e.g.,

```
lemma diff_induct: "(!!x. P x 0) ==> (!!y. P 0 (Suc y)) ==>
    (!!x y. P x y ==> P (Suc x) (Suc y)) ==> P m n"
  apply (rule_tac x = m in spec)
  apply (induct n)
  prefer 2
  apply (rule allI)
  apply (induct_tac x, iprover+)
  done
```

I want to see only

```
lemma diff_induct: "(!!x. P x 0) ==> (!!y. P 0 (Suc y)) ==>
    (!!x y. P x y ==> P (Suc x) (Suc y)) ==> P m n"
```

The reason is that I use the HTML pages to look what theorems are available, but the proofs are only distracting in that case. (I know that omitting proofs is possible when generating a PDF, but I am specifically interested in the HTML documentation.)

Comment: In the context of Isabelle, the question is perfectly understandable and valid.

Comment: You can make your induction lemma stronger: `(!! x. P x 0) ==> (!! y. (!! x. P x y) ==> P 0 (Suc y)) ==> (!! y. (!! x. P x y) ==> (!! x. P (Suc x) (Suc y))) ==> P x y`. Use `apply (induct y arbitrary: x, auto) apply (case_tac x, auto)`. But that's not what you asked...

Comment: To see what theorems are available `find_theorems` (with proper search criteria) might be a better solution than reading through an abundance of HTML files.

Comment: @chris: `find_theorems` is certainly an important tool. But sometimes I find it very helpful to read through the whole theory to find out what is available.

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately currently no built-in way to do this in Isabelle (HTML generation used to include a digest a number of years ago, but that is no longer provided).

You could think about post-processing generated HTML files, but this is more complex than it may sound.

Your best bets currently are the outline PDF and, as Chris suggests, using a command like

```
find_theorems name: "MyThy."
```

to get a list of all theorems in theory `MyThy`. You can augment the `find_theorems` command with term expressions or just constant names to narrow your search to specific constants. This is usually more effective than browsing through long lists of theorems. You can similarly use the command `find_consts` to find constants by type, constant name, or theory name, e.g. to get a list of all constants defined in one theory.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently came across `coqdoc` output, and can understand that question from that standpoint, although the Coq HTML pages now also show their age.

In Isabelle the HTML presentation was once very important, then other tools like the online `find_theorems` or offline PDF documents became more powerful and useful, and now there is also Isabelle/jEdit with display qualities that approximate HTML browsers from the time when Isabelle HTML output was first implemented.

I don't know of an easy way to get what you ask in contemporary Isabelle2013, but it is not impossible, mostly requires some renovation of old stuff to fit to new concepts.  Since HTML browsing with static web pages is a bit old-fashioned these days, it did not get top priority so far.

In any case, Isabelle/Scala (which is the official Isabelle system programming interface) already provides some public API operations to get XML trees from the PIDE document markup that you see online in Isabelle/jEdit, for example.  From there it is not very far to some HTML + CSS, for people who understand that business.  It might be quicker and more useful, though, to make some presentation in Isabelle/jEdit, bypassing the multitude of web browsers and their quirks.